# How to connect sql database with ignite cluster to sync data?

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server, ignite, thin-client

I am new to apache ignite. I created ignite cluster and connect my nodejs thin client to it. It is working fine but It only create cache create functions specified in js file. Now I want to sync my sql server data with ignite. Any idea how I will do it?

I tried to connect with Grid gain but it does not allow me to create free cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to [3rd Party Persistence](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/3rd-party-store#section-rdbms-integration) documentation regarding RDBMS integration.

[GridGain Web Console](https://console.gridgain.com) can help you [set up database integration](https://apacheignite-tools.readme.io/docs/automatic-rdbms-integration) by generating Maven project corresponding to your RDBMS data model.

GridGain Community Edition is free to use as long as you deploy it on your own. But, it is also supported by stock Apache Ignite.